# Xpath get element above

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

suppose I have this structure:

```
<div class="a" attribute="foo">
    <div class="b">
        <span>Text Example</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In xpath, I would like to retrieve the value of the attribute "attribute" given I have the text inside: Text Example

If I use this xpath:

```
.//*[@class='a']//*[text()='Text Example']
```

It returns the element span, but I need the div.a, because I need to get the value of the attribute through Selenium WebDriver

Answer (score 10):

Hey there are lot of ways by which you can figure it out.

So lets say `Text Example` is given, you can identify it using this text:-

```
//span[text()='Text Example']/../..         --> If you know its 2 level up
```

OR

```
//span[text()='Text Example']/ancestor::div[@class='a']  --> If you don't know how many level up this `div` is
```

Above 2 `xpaths` can be used if you only want to identify the element using `Text Example`, if you don't want to iterate through this text. There are simple ways to identify it directly:-

```
//div[@class='a']
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question itself you have mentioned the answer for it

> but I need the **div.a**,

try this

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.a")).getAttribute("attribute");
```

use cssSelector for best result.

or else try the following xpath

```
//div[contains(@class, 'a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want attribute of `div.a` with it's [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) `span` which contains `text` something, try as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'a' and descendant::span[text() = 'Text Example']]")).getAttribute("attribute");
```

Hope it helps..:)